# insert element at bottom of stack

Tags: c++, insert, stack

I am doing the Insert at Bottom of the stack question.
This code is perfectly working in the CodeStudio but it is not giving the correct expected output in Visual studio code. why it is not displaying all the elements of the stack

```
# include <iostream>
# include <stack>
# include <vector>
# include <string>
using namespace std;

void Helper(stack<int>& myStack, int x){

    if(myStack.empty()){
      myStack.push(x);
      return ;
    }
    int temp=myStack.top();
    myStack.pop();
    Helper(myStack, x);
    myStack.push(temp);
 

}

stack<int> pushAtBottom(stack<int>& myStack, int x) 
{
     Helper(myStack,x);
    return myStack;
}

int main(){
 stack<int> s,ans;
 int n,a;
 cout<<"How many element : ";
 cin>>n;
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cin>>a;
    s.push(a);
 }
  cout<<"New element : ";
 cin>>a;


 ans=pushAtBottom(s,a);
  cout<<"After inserting : ";
  for(int i=0; i<ans.size(); i++){

    cout<<ans.top()<<" ";
    ans.pop();
 }
 cout<<endl;
 return 0;

}
```

**Input**

```
6

1 2 3 4 5
```

**Expected Output**

```
5 4 3 2 1 6
```

**Output**

```
After inserting : 5 4 3
```

Comment: By definition, if you need to insert elements at both ends, you are not using a stack. You might be able to abuse a stack to do this, but it's simply the wrong data structure here.

Comment: yeah, thank you  @PeteBecker. I know but I was just trying to do it by using stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you print the elements:

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<ans.size(); i++){
    cout<<ans.top()<<" ";
    ans.pop();
}
```

Due to calling `ans.pop()` `ans.size()` will *decrease* by one every iteration. At the same time `i` will *increase* by one every iteration. Basically you iterate twice as fast as intended.

A better loop would be this:

```cpp
while(ans.size() > 0) {
    cout << ans.top() << " ";
    ans.pop();
}
```